# What happens if I add the same path twice to a Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, elastic-map-reduce

I am using elastic map reduce. I wonder what will happen if I use the exact same line twice in my main method.

> FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(
>                           "s3n://mybucket/data/lolcat/*"));

Will hadoop process the same files twice ? Or will it figure out that they are the same files and will skip the duplicates ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the source that adds the input paths:

```
public static void addInputPath(JobConf conf, Path path ) {
    path = new Path(conf.getWorkingDirectory(), path);
    String dirStr = StringUtils.escapeString(path.toString());
    String dirs = conf.get("mapred.input.dir");
    conf.set("mapred.input.dir", dirs == null ? dirStr :
      dirs + StringUtils.COMMA_STR + dirStr);
}
```

So as you can see it just appends your input into **mapred.input.dir** without looking at the content before.

Besides the `getSplits` function only uses `List` and no `Set`, so if you have the same input paths N times it will be processed N times. Tested on a Hadoop streaming job, I get twice the amount of mappers if I duplicate the same input path.